# Display File Extension in Doc. Library Column?

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, list-view, file-upload

I need to display the file extensions of the files in a Document library in a column. I have done a bunch of searching and came across solutions but they don't seem to be working for me.

This is what I have been trying to do:

1. Open SPD and select my list
2. Select the view that I want to add file extension column to
3. Since I already created the column in the list setting on SP I just right-click in the first row of that column and 'Insert Formula', then enter this: @FileLeafRef.Suffix

Now nothing happens, my items don't show the extensions in the column in SPD and not in SP either.

Is there something I am doing wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using as a formula

```
string(@LinkFilename)
```

should return the full name (extension included) of the document (notice that using @FileLeafRef should return the same results). So, if you want to use @FileLeafRef you should strip the name from the returned string. This formula

```
ddwrt:GetFileExtension(string(@FileLeafRef ))
```

should give the expected result.

As an alternative, you should be able to use:

```
@File_x0020_Type
```

(see [this link](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/articles/how-to-show-file-extensions-in-sharepoint-2007-document-lists), provided with screenshot).

Comment: For some reason simply @FileLeafRef just didn't work for me but this does ddwrt:GetFileExtension(string(@FileLeafRef )) 
Thanks! SPArchaeologist!

Comment: Glad you worked it out. You could also try and see if the linked tutorial (the one using @File_x0020_Type) works, but I guess there is no need for that if the other solution is working.

Comment: I actually tried selecting FileType from the list which would give the @File_x0020_Type if I'm not mistaken...but that did not work, the only one I was able to get working was the GetFileExtension that you mentioned. However, the FileLeafRef worked fine on another server and environment, so I don't really have any idea why some of the options work and others don't

Comment: It *could* be something related to the list content types, available fields or view definitions. Anyway, since you got it working, I would avoid to open that can of worms ^_^'

Answer (score 0):

The way I found that I like so far for "New/Modern" SharePoint is to modify the view to show **Name (for use in forms)**

1. For myself, I select **All Documents / Switch View Options**
   [image: Selecting "All Documents / Switch View Options"]
2. In the **Columns** section, put a check mark next to the column called **Name (for use in forms)**
   [image: Selecting Name (for use in forms) in Edit View / Switch View Options]
3. Set the positioning of the column by selecting the appropriate positioning number.
4. Click **OK** when done.
5. Now the Document List will display the file extension for the uploaded files.
   [image: The names now have the extensions included in the Name column]

[Source](https://ppmworks.com/file-extension-in-sharepoint-list/)